# Swift 4 - Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: xcode, swift4

I'm trying to record a score and Highscore on a game that I'm doing. But I've been getting this error:

[image]

Any clues of how can I fix this? I have Xcode 10 and I'm working with Swift 4. Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ScoreVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var highscoreLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var reset: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var points: UIButton!

    var Score = 0
    var Highscore = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let HighscoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard

        if (HighscoreDefault.value(forKey: "Highscore") != nil) {
            Highscore = HighscoreDefault.value(forKey: "Highscore") as! Int
            highscoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Highscore: %i", Highscore) as String
        }
    }

    @IBAction func resetButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Score = 0
        scoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score) as String
    }

    @IBAction func pointsButton(_ sender: Any) {
        Score +=
        scoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score) as String
        if (Score > Highscore) {
            Highscore = Score
            highscoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Highscore: %i", Highscore) as String

            var HighscoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
            HighscoreDefault.setValue(Highscore, forKey: "Highscore")
            HighscoreDefault.synchronize()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the line above it, you have `Score +=`. What is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also, you don't have to, but I **strongly** recommend that you start variable names with a lowercase following camelcase instead of capitals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case

Comment: The Score += adds the same value of Score. Basically is like Score + Score. btw, I just put the CamelCase.

Comment: No, that's not what `+=` does.  It adds the value after it, which in this case is on the next line (and therefore causes your error).  You want `Score += Score` or `Score *= 2`.

Comment: You dont have to use NSString either. String also has a formatting method.

Comment: Lots of other problems unrelated to the immediate issue: 1. Don't use `NSString`. `String` supports formatting too. Use `scoreLabel.text = String(format: "Score: %i", Score)` or just `scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(Score)"`. 2. Don't use `value(forKey:)` or `setValue(_:forKey:)` with `UserDefaults`. Those are for key-value coding. Use the provided methods listed in the documentation for `UserDefaults`. 3. Don't call `synchronize`. It's obsolete. See the documentation. 4. Variable and function names should start with lowercase. Class names start with uppercase.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still new to this. 1. Yes. What I'm trying to do with += is to add an extra point to the score. 2. I will remove the NSString. 3. I will do all the changes suggested. I'll get back once I got this fixed.

Comment: ok. I took all the recommendations and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this line from `pointsButton`:

```
Score += 1
```

As to the error message,

```
scoreLabel.text = NSString(format: "Score: %i", Score) as String
```

Here `scoreLabel.text` is an *lvalue* since it exists on the left of the assignment operator `=`. In the line before, in your original code, `Score +=` was expecting an *rvalue* and the assignment operation can't be treated as an rvalue.

Comment: It's possible this is supposed to be `Score += 1` to increment the score.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes probably, I didn't want to make any assumptions since the name of the function `pointsButton` isn't synonymous with increasing a score

Comment: Yep. It's supposed to increase the score one by one.

Answer (score 3):

Edit this line from pointsButton :

```
guard let scoreLabel = scoreLabel.text else {
    return
}
```