# Getting warning xpression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: swift, xcode

I am reading a value from a UITextField and setting to my model property. Like this

```
currentPlace.elevation = Double(elevation.text)
```

But I am seeing this warning message

> xpression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context

**My model class is this**

```
class PlaceDescription {

    var elevation: Double?
    var placeName: String?

}
```

**And my ViewController class is this**

```
class AddPlaceViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var elevation: UITextField!
     @IBOutlet weak var placeName: UITextField!
     var currentPlace = PlaceDescription()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         currentPlace.elevation = Double(elevation.text) //<-I am getting warning here 
         currentPlace.placeName = placeName.text //<- This works fine
     }

}
```

I am new to IOS Application development. My questions are,

1. What does this error really mean?
2. How to fix this?

#### Note: I have found related questions on StackOverflow but none seem to solve my problem.

[Related question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56752579/what-does-error-expression-type-lvalue-string-is-ambiguous-without-more-con/56752735)
[Related question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55056650/expression-type-lvalue-string-is-ambiguous-without-more-context-when-to-u/55056696#55056696)
[Related Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52655459/swift-4-expression-type-lvalue-string-is-ambiguous-without-more-context)

Comment: The error I get for this is `Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'String?' conform to 'StringProtocol'`. What version of Xcode/Swift are you using?

Comment: Xcode 10 @Jessy

Comment: That's too old!  Get yourself an 11.4 beta!

Comment: I am required to do it in Xcode 10 because it is a strict requirement.(I know its strange. But it is what it is) I use Xcode 11 as well. @Jessy

Comment: Just to note, I replicated the problem on my rig (Xcode 11.3.1), and I also get the same error message as OP, so it probably isn't because he is using Xcode 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Xcode says that a ***type or expression is ambiguous without more context***, the compiler is letting you know that the expression you have provided is not specific enough, and it cannot be evaluated properly unless you give it more context (i.e. make it more specific).

In your specific case, it is complaining because you're trying to initialize a Double from an optional String . If you **unwrap it**, it should remove the warning:

```
Double(elevation.text ?? "")
```

The text property of UITextField is an **optional**.  It is not a String. That's the problem.  Swift treats optionals as a completely different type.

**EDIT**

As helpfully explained by @Jessy, a better solution for this is:

```
currentPlace.elevation = elevation.text.flatMap(Double.init)
```

This will still return `nil` if `elevation.text` is `nil`, preserving OP's intent, since elevation is also an optional.

Comment: A better representation of what Rohit wants to express is  `elevation.text.flatMap(Double.init)`.

Comment: I have other properties as well which are String. It does not give me error for that line. Ill update the question for better understanding

Comment: The problem does not lie with `Strings`, but with Optionals.  You needed to unwrap the text property before being able to convert it to a double.

Comment: And what I'm saying is that you don't want to convert `nil` into a `Double`, requiring the `?? ""`—that makes things compile but doesn't represent intent. You want `nil` if `text is nil`, which an `Optional.map`-style operation. Converting a `String` into a `Double` is failable, so you need `flatMap` to express this, not just `map`. `elevation.text.map(Double.init)` returns `Double??`, which is one more level of optionality than your property.

Comment: I hear you Jessy.  I'll update my answer to include your suggestion if that works for you.